# JPA Java mapping relations

Tags: java, jpa, mapping

In Java, I have a superclass Element and 4 subclasses, lets call them ElementA, ElementB, ElementC, ElementD.

Tables in my DB:

```
Element(ElementID, title, description, targetGroup) : Primary key elementID  
ElementA(ElementID,...) : Foreign key elementID   
ElementB(ElementID,...) : Foreign key elementID   
ElementC(ElementID,...) : Foreign key elementID  
ElemendD(ElementID,...) : Foreign key elementID
```

I also have: LearningProgram and LearningProgramElement:

```
LearningProgram(programcode, ....) : Primary key programcode  
LearningProgramElement(programcode, ElementID, dateFrom, dateUntil, ...) : Foreign key programcode, Foreign key elementID
```

LearningProgramElement links an Element to a LearningProgram and also has some attributes of this relation:
An element can be in different LearningPrograms but will have different dateForm and dateUntil in each LearningProgram.

Now in my Java I have in a LearningProgram object 4 lists:

```
List<LearningProgramElement> elementA = new ArrayList<>();  
List<LearningProgramElement> elementB = new ArrayList<>();  
List<LearningProgramElement> elementC = new ArrayList<>();  
List<LearningProgramElement> elementD = new ArrayList<>();
```

A LearningProgram object looks like this:

```
private String programcode;
private int elementid;
...
private Element element;
```

I now get 4 times the same list, containing ALL LearningProgramElement's.
How can I make my jpa annotations that in list elementA there are only LearningProgramElement's who have an Element of subclass ElementA, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I think @MappedSuperClass is what you want.  Check out the docs on that and see if the examples match your use case.